The difference in meaning between conjunctions
Is it true  that when we use "provided that, on condition that, as long as and only if" we show that we want somethin to happen? For instance

We won't have fun provided that/on condition that/as long as/only if it rains soon

Does it show that we desire  rain and therefore the sentence it just stupid?
On other hand would 2 work?

we will have fun provided that/on condition that/as long as/only if you visit us


Those conjunctions are not perfectly interchangeable.  You won't find "as long as", for example, in a contract written by traditional lawyers, but "provided that" or "on condition that".

I think the question is far too broad.  Asking about "provided that" and "on conditon" that in one question would be OK, but adding "only if" and "as long as" to the mix requires a treatise for an answer.

Those are not conjunctions like and, or, but etc.

Those conjunctions introduce provisos.
A proviso is a condition that must be met in order for some other action to take place. It is a necessary condition but may not be a sufficient condition.

Offenders will be imprisoned for a minimum of ten years, provided they have had two or more previous offenses.

One could substitute "on condition that", or "as long as", or "only if" there.  But "as long as" might sound "tone-deaf" to some.
Rather than puzzle out what is desirable or undesirable about imprisonment, forget about desirability, and focus on the proviso as a condition that must be met if some action is to be triggered, although meeting the condition may not be sufficient cause to trigger the action:

A well thought-out paper that considers the subject from multiple angles will be given a good grade, provided you have not plagiarized anything.

Not having fun is not an "action".


I think this wouldn't work "We won't deliver the package provided/ on condition that you have that vicious dog untethered.", right? 2) What if I used "only if" in that sentence?


That which is made possible by the proviso's terms being met must be expressed with positive polarity. Or with a phrase which, in a conversational context, is understood in that way.   "OK. We won't release these salacious photos of you onto the internet, provided you pay us $1 million in bitcoin by midnight tonight."  There, "OK" casts the promise not to do something as an action the blackmailers will take: they will suppress the photos. They are casting it as a concession they're willing to make.  That is not what seems to be going on with your vicious dog scenario and "only if".

but you used as long as in a negative context why?

@marta You are misunderstaning how "negative" and "positive" are used in a grammatical context. It has nothing to do with desirability or unfortunate circumstances. https://languagetools.info/grammarpedia/polarity.htm  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item

@TimR so it is possible to say in formal style " we won't be albe to make a deal provided she comes:?

@thomas: No, that is a bad sentence. The word "provided" should be changed to "if" or "if she comes" could be changed to "should she come" or "if she should come".  But please stop using inane verbs like "comes". Say something like "if she is part of the deal" or anything that make sense in context.  I know you mean that as a "throwaway" clause but try to get in the habit of being more realistic. In what "formal style" would you ever use the phrase "if she comes"?

Moreover, you could not not use that sentence in an informal conversation either. It is misusing "provided". It is not a stylistic matter. It is using the word improperly. Move the negative to the proviso :  We are close to making a deal, provided she is not involved. We can make a deal, provided she is not involved.

provided that/on condition that/as long as/only if  are not conjunctions.

@Lambie Let's leave contentious grammatical analysis aside.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/provided-that

@Lambie I too would not call it a conjunction

Your sentence (1) is very strange. We normally use expressions like provided that to talk about something good that can only happen if the circumstances are right. Talking about an outdoor event:

We will have fun provided that it doesn't rain.

Not having fun isn't a desirable situation, so we wouldn't talk about it's being conditional on something else happening.

My garden should be all right provided that it rains soon.

Here, you are hoping for rain to water the garden.
As for (2), it makes sense but isn't very idiomatic. It would be more natural to say

We won't have any fun unless you are here.

or

We won't have so much fun if you can't come.


it applies to all 4 conjunctions, right that we only use them to express a desiarable condition not just to provided that?

@thomas - I haven't time to think about all possible uses of all four phrases, but yes, such expressions are normally used to express the condition necessary for a desirable outcome.

Desirability is one possible context. What is desirable in the following?  We won't deliver the package as long as you have that vicious dog untethered.

@TimR - True. Of course it can be reversed as "We will deliver the package on condition/provided that you tie up your dog".
